# Loop over all the samples of Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to loop over all the samples of my data; here is how it looks and the shape of it:

```
processed_data3
array([[[[1.81673904e-05, 5.00669221e-01],
         [1.65148740e-02, 5.52741534e-01],
         [1.55841024e-02, 4.39919449e-01],
         ...,
         [3.80455403e-03, 5.00042373e-01],
         [6.80686618e-01, 4.78582767e-01],
         [7.49290676e-04, 5.30804954e-01]],
```

```
processed_data3.shape
(100, 64, 256, 2)
```

I would like to loop over all the 100 samples of the data and do the same as what I am doing for only one sample:

```
mask = np.zeros([64,256])
for i in range(64):
    for j in range(256):
        if processed_data3[0,i,j,0] >0.1:
            mask[i,j] = 1
```

Basically I would like to store a mask for each of these 100 samples in the its own mask array, but I am not sure how to do that. Any suggestions based on this one sample?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` to achieve the desired result. No loops necessary. Try this:

```
mask = np.where(processed_data3>0.1, 1, 0)[0][0]
```